# Resharper 6 online analysis memory

Tags: resharper

After upgrading to R# v6 I am unpleasantly surprised to see that the memory usage for the same application is using almost three (3) times what it did with v5.x, and is *painfully* slow. Not sure I would upgrade again if I had known this before hand.

Is this a known issue? Has anyone noticing the same jump been able to successfully tweak this?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're receiving mixed reports on memory and performance consumption in v6. In some cases, users call the new version a massive improvement over previous versions, other times they report increased memory consumption and lags in certain scenarios. This is pretty much the same story with every new version.

There are several known issues related to [processing classic ASP files](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-80754#comment=27-249625) and in general [processing source file on solution load](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-274042). Both have been addressed lately and will be fixed in ReSharper 6.1 that is coming out later this Fall.

I suggest that you do the following:

1. Try to clean ReSharper caches by deleting *YourSolutionName.suo* and *_ReSharper.YourSolutionName* folder - this helps sometimes.
2. Downgrade to ReSharper 5.1.3 for the time being. This version is available via [ReSharper archive](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-280).
3. As soon as ReSharper 6.1 comes out, install it to see if it's any better.
4. If it's no better, [profile ReSharper](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Profiling+Instructions) and send the profile to us for investigation.

An alternative would be to profile 6.0 right away as there's a chance that your issue is something we've not yet investigated during 6.1 development.

Comment: I've been on R# since v3 and never experienced performance *this* bad - what a pig! I think you all rushed this one out the door too early...

Comment: Well we have actually overtimed it: should have released in April, released last day of June. Believe me, it happens all the time: a release is being stabilized, optimized (based on snapshots and feedback) and what not, then goes to the public, and BANG! we have a subset of users who say they haven't ever experienced performance that bad. You're unfortunately one of them this time. It's either we've misunderstanding something fundamental in terms of QA or the amount of possible usage scenarios is just plain overwhelming (or both.) BTW, do you have any more VS plug-ins installed?